# EmailJS is not working after the april update in flutter

Tags: flutter, email

I tried to create an automatic emailing service in my flutter application using EmailJS, and did as it was mentioned in the documentation, but in the part where we have to specify the user_id, it was written in the documentation, that it is the Public key of my account. But, using the Public Key of my account as the user_id, gives me the following error:

```
The Public Key is required. To find this ID, visit https://dashboard.emailjs.com/account
```

My code for using the service is:

```
Future<void> sendEmailToParents() async{
print('send email to parents :))');
final serviceId='service_fm3ymlj';
final templateId='template_ru9gpkp';
final userId='SaGQJusVSIxIMGhiw';
print(userId);
final url = Uri.parse('https://api.emailjs.com/api/v1.0/email/send');
final response=await http.post(
    url,
  headers:{
      'ContentType': 'application/json',
  },
  body: json.encode({
      'service_id': serviceId,
      'template_id': templateId,
      'key': userId,
    'template_params': {
        'lost_child_name': _name,
        'user_name':_username,
        'user_contact_number':_user_contact_number,
        'user_email':widget.email,
        'location':_location,
        'police_address':_registered_lost_at,
        "parent's_email":_parent_email,
       // "child_img_url": image1
    },
  })
);

print(response.body);
}
```

Can someone please guide me on where am I going wrong? I used the public key from here

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I had a problem, the response code was 400, after I checked the box
security->Allow EmailJS API for non-browser applications.
everything worked.
And you need to specify a private key if it is in security->Use Private Key (recommended).

Answer (score 1):

Add `'origin': 'http://localhost'` in the header

Answer (score 1):

[EmailJS account page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLKsz.png) By default API calls are disabled for non-browser applications
You need to activate API requests through Account Security, you'd find a checkbox there to enable this feature.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).